# Which is faster ? own private DNS (Windows/Linux) or Public DNS (Google, Cloudflare, etc.)

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I'm trying to get the fastest DNS solution for my private network (at home for my labs).
I have Windows and Linux workstations and VMs.

I need the fastest DNS solution but I don't know what to choose.
In your opinion which is the fastest DNS method ?

1. Windows dedicated private DNS server ?
2. Linux dedicated private DNS server Bind9 vs alternatives ?
3. Cloud private DNS (AWS / Azure / Google Cloud) ?
4. Public DNS as Cloudlfare (1.1.1.1/1.0.0.1) or Google (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4) etc ?

Thanks

Comment: Which names you are going to resolve? If something public and random, your local DNS would be almost certainly slower, because the speed of resolution limited by the recursive process, not by the dns-client-to-resolver-server network delay. If something easily cacheable, local could be faster, because cache will heat up fast and then resolution would be done over low-delay local network.

Comment: Hi, in fact I need to resolve public IP like Netflix, Google, Steam, GOG, AWS etc.

Comment: I suggest you to try any of them and test which one is faster for you. Because this depends on many conditions. Also don't miss an option to use hosts file (see answer below), if you have to do mainly A-type RRs to query and there is restricted number of names (of around 1000), consider that as a hand-made static cache. Unfortunately, if you are going to query anything else, it won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Local network

The fastest is NOT to use DNS but use the hosts file for looking up the addresses of your own systems.

In general you can’t use public resolvers for reverse lookups concerning your local network, so if/when you want/need to have that configured and don’t want to configure and maintain  hosts files  you are required to run a local DNS server.

There are indeed many different DNS servers you can run yourself for your own network but I can’t recommend one over the other.

## Internet addresses

In general DNS servers can offer the fastest response when a record is cached and the response will be slower if first an authoritative server needs to be determined and contacted for a query that isn’t cached yet.

In general that makes large public resolvers faster as they will have many more cached records and expired records will be refreshed more frequently than when operate your own DNS server (without a forwarder).

Comment: So if I understand I should use the public DNS (Cloudflare / Google) to resolve public addresses and use the hosts file to resolve private addresses that's right ?

Comment: nope, if you often use the same a local resolver can /may- be faster, as it sonly delivers it from the cache on a lan request but in fact would only be usually useful if you have a couple od clients